# What it is the most efficient way to shift and add extra row of data to match delta using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What would be the most efficient way to use pandas to align and shift the data to add an extra row with 0 in A or B columns if the Difference is higher than 2 ABS, in order to recursively make the Difference of A-B < 2 ex.-

```
[Column A]  [Diff A - B]   [Column B] 
0                0             0 
4.54             4.54          0       <-- Need to add a 0 to shift
4.54             0             4.54
4.54             0             4.54
4.54            -3.04          1.5


    After added  
[Column A]  [Diff A - B]   [Column B] 
    0                0             0 
    0                0             0 
    0               -4.54          4.54    <--Recursive Need to do same
    4.54             0             4.54
    4.54             0             4.54
    4.54            -3.04          1.5
```

The whole idea its to push the data to match on a lower diff. If you notice i need to add and shift every time that i find a diff absolute higher than 2 on Column A or Column B

Answer (score 1):

- split the dataframe into before and after
  `df0, df1 = df.iloc[:1], df.iloc[1:]`
- create a series of what goes in between
  `s = pd.Series(0, df.columns).to_frame().T`
- concatenate all 3
  `pd.concat([df0, s, df1], ignore_index=True)`

---

```
df0, df1 = df.iloc[:1], df.iloc[1:]
s = pd.Series(0, df.columns).to_frame().T
pd.concat([df0, s, df1], ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @piRSquared thanks for answering. But I already have that part I was asking more on how the data can be shifted to align it to add extra zeros on the data in order to make the difference shorter on the "Diff" column I am not very good on recursivity